# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : action result method creation - best approach

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC. Please guide me the best approach for a methods creation in controllers and displaying in razor view.

**Task #1**: read json from URL and display as ordered list in Razor view.

I have used the below code in the controller for this:

```
public void GetCatalogsUsingJson() 
{
     ///Somecode///  
     ViewBag.TPartyJsonCtgls = dictresults.Keys;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
     GetCatalogsUsingJson();            
     return View();  
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(K360ecommerceMaster K360LevelAMap)
{ 
    GetCatalogsUsingJson();            
    return View();        
}
```

**Task #2**: during Http post, insert into database.

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(K360ecommerceMaster K360LevelAMap)
{
    this.KContext.K360ecommerceMasters.Add(K360LevelAMap);
    this.KContext.SaveChanges();
    GetCatalogsUsingJson();
    return View(K360LevelAMap);
}
```

In view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">ProductCatalogs Mapping</button><form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Map360">
```

**Task #3**: fetch records from SQL database and display it as data table in the view.

In controller:

```
public void GeMappedDataDt()
{
    var resultMappedData = this.KContext.K360ecommerceMasters.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM K360ECommerce_Master WHERE ThirdParty_Key is NOT NULL").ToList();
    ViewBag.K360MappedData = resultMappedData;
}
```

In view:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>K360KeyValue</th>
        <th>K360KeyText</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (K360ecommerceMaster Mappeddata in ViewBag.K360MappedData)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Mappeddata.ThirdPartyKey</td>
        <td>@Mappeddata.K360ProductCatalog</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I am very confused about using `IAction` result method during `HttpPost` call.  I need to know about difference in using below `IAction` methods.

```
public IActionResult MethodName(Parameters)

public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName(Parameters)
```

I am using the first of these two methods. Please guide me the best approach.

Comment: The `IActionResult` is synchronous, the `Task<IActionResult>` is asynchronous. By convention, the method identifiers of the latter will often end in `Async`, but this is optional—and will be stripped by ASP.NET Core as part of routing. You _must_ use the asynchronous method if your action `await`s asynchronous calls; conversely, if you don’t, then Code Analysis will warn you that you have an unnecessary `async` method. From an end user perspective, there’s no significant difference in how these are handled, so the easiest measure is to use `Task<IActionResult>` when you have asynchronous code.

Comment: **_Note:_** Because ASP.NET Core can route to either based on the same route data, you can switch between these later without impacting HTTP clients. The change will (obviously) affect unit tests, but as that’s internal code, that shouldn’t be a big concern. As such, I wouldn’t fret too much over this distinction right now. There are other architectural decisions that will have a bigger immediate impact on your code, such as using view models with strongly typed views.

Comment: As Jeremy said, [the IActionResult is synchronous, the Task<IActionResult> is asynchronous](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#synchronous-action).So, I assume you want to compare the Async/Sync Actions, please refer to [this article](https://gokhansengun.com/asp-net-mvc-and-web-api-comparison-of-async-or-sync-actions/), the Async actions are not improving overall scalability and performance of an application.They are able to scale I/O bound applications so that they can better utilize the resources.So, I prefer to use the Async method.